# How to generate Model classes for existing AzureCosmosDB?

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have an existing Azure CosmosDB with all the data and collections. Now I am looking to generate the Model classes based on the same process that I did for SQLServer database.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/walkthroughs/existing-database

I tried the below command using the cmd utility navigating to the folder which contains the solution file :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold <Azure CosmosDB ConnectionString> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos -o Models
```

On executing the above command I get the below error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find expected assembly attribute named DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute in provider assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos. This attribute is required to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider factory.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices(String provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build(String provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to find expected assembly attribute named DesignTimeProviderServicesAttribute in provider assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos. This attribute is required to identify the class which acts as the design-time service provider factory.
```

Can anyone help me to know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, the database provider needs to contain information about how to do the scaffolding. At this time, CosmosDB does not support this so you will not be able to use the CLI to create models from an existing database.

There is a [Github issue open](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14629) to improve the error message to make this more clear. If you'd like, you can open an issue on that repo requesting the feature be added for Cosmos.